# Regex match alphanumeric inside quotes inside inside square bracket inside parentheses

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match the alphanumeric value or the string inside the following items:

```
IMDB(["tt3107288"])
```

now I tried with escaping the `(` and the `[` but I am lost on how to escape the `"` using this:

```
'IMDB\(\[([^]]+)\]'
```

this reports the value `"tt3107288"`  with the quotes... I know I can just replace the quotes but it would be more efficient just to match the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parentheses and brackets have special meaning in regex, so you'll have to escape them. Also, your expression has unbalanced parentheses.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'IMDB\(\["([^"]+)"\]\)', 'IMDB(["tt3107288"])').group(1)
'tt3107288'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
"([^"]+)"
```

and now the only captured group will be your desired portion.

**Example:**

```
In [2]: s = 'IMDB(["tt3107288"])'

In [3]: re.search(r'"([^"]+)"', s).group(1)
Out[3]: 'tt3107288'
```